# I have been there

Tags: grammar, tense, difference

Is it possible to say “I have been there in May.”
Or do I have to say “I went there in May.” if I want to say
Date?

I’ll appreciate it if you teach me.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can say, “I went there in May.”

You’re onto something about providing the date. If you don’t provide a specific timeframe, you can simply say, “I have been there **before**.” But that sounds a little awkward when you provide the time, unless you punctuate it differently. So, you could write:

> I have been there – in May.

which is like a shortened form of:

> I have been there [before]. [I went] in May.